# How to get list of Active Directory group names beginning with "ABC_" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to get a list of Active Directory items that start with the same naming convention for example I have a number of groups beginning with "ABC_Group1", "ABC_Group2", "ABC_Group3".

I know that:

```
get-adgroup "ABC_Group1"
```

will list that specific group

```
'get-adgroup -filter * | sort name | select Name'
```

will list all the groups but I don't know how to filter to find just the specific groups starts with "ABC_"

I then want to list it's members.

Comment: Use ABC_* as a wildcard with match operator in where condition.

Comment: @RanadipDutta I'm  new to powershell, could you give bit more detail. I'm not sure how to use this.

Comment: I have marked as an answer. You can use it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use Wildcard search with Where condition. In the newer PS version, the where clause can be used as `Filter`

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like 'ABC_*'}  -Properties * | select -property SamAccountName,Name,Description,DistinguishedName,CanonicalName,GroupCategory,GroupScope,whenCreated
```

Since the OP asked to get the members of the group as well, here is the piece of code which will help you:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like 'ABC_*'} -SearchBase "DC=YourDC" | Get-ADGroupMember -Partition "DC=YourDC"
```

**OR**

```
Get-ADGroup 'Group Name' -Properties Member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member
```

**OR use Dot notation:**

```
(Get-ADGroup 'Group Name' -Properties Member).Member
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this works, do you know how I would be able to list the members from these groups that we've selected?

Comment: @A.Codes: Yup. You modify your question and meanwhile , I will modify the answer

Answer (score 1):

I've done some research and played around with the code and it turns out,

`Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*ABC_*'" | sort name` lists all the groups that have "ABC_"

However, this also means it will list directories such as "Group_ABC_". However, I only want to list directories that START with "ABC_"

Answer (score 0):

Well, wouldn't it be enough to just remove the "*" in front of the ABC?

So `'*ABC_*'` would turn into `'ABC_*'` and therefore be
`Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like 'ABC_*'" | sort name`

I highly recommend you to read yourself into Regular Expressions, you wont need it for this task but it can make you're life so much easier regarding pattern matching in strings and similar cases